# how to get fully qualified directory in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This is the structure of my directory:

`/rabbitProps`, `/app` and`/app/xyz`

There is a bash script that i need to edit. In the bash script, there is a variable called BASEDIR and that has the value of "/app/xyz". I need to essentially concatenate the directory of `/rabbitProps` to a variable called `CLASSPATH` in the script but not sure how to do that. This is my if statement in the script:

```
amqDirectory=${BASEDIR}/../rabbitProps/
echo $amqDirectory
echo $BASEDIR
if [ -d "$amqDirectory" ]; then
  echo "--SETTING rabbitProps PROPERTIES"
  echo "In the if statement for setting rabbitProps"
  echo $amqDirectory
  CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${amqDirectory}"
else
  echo "--NOT SETTING AMQ PROPERTIES"
  echo "In the else if statement for setting amq_properties"
  echo $amqDirectory
fi
echo $BASEDIR
echo $CLASSPATH
```

but it keeps on going to the else block. when i print out the `amqDirectory` variable, it has the value of `/app/xyz/../rabbitProps/` ... which is probably why it's failing the if condition. Can someone correct the expression? I'm not really familiar with bash.

Comment: The conditon will fail if the directory doesn't exist. It's not clear from your whether it actually should exist; clearly, it doesn't. Bash (and the rest of the system) doesn't care if the directory name is absolute or relative, though you probably wat your `CLASSPATH` (and generally any system variable) to contain absolute paths, so that it works correctly regardless of your working directory.

Answer (score 3):

Change your line `amqDirectory=${BASEDIR}/../rabbitProps/` to the following

```
amqDirectory=$(realpath "${BASEDIR}/../rabbitProps/")
```

Utility `realpath` gives the resolved path

If the utility is not available, you could do it this way

```
amqDirectory=$(cd "$BASEDIR/../rabbitProps/"; pwd)
```

Also, directory is not changed to $BASEDIR/../rabbitProps/ after executing above command as $(..) does the command substitution and it invokes sub-shell for executing commands

Comment: I tried this but get the following: `realpath: command not found`. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is your shell? bash or ksh or any other ( you can check it with `echo $0` in a terminal)

Comment: it says `-bash` when i write that command

Comment: If the command `realpath` is not available in your shell ( if you get errors for commands `type realpath` or `typeset -a realpath` 

Then you could do this 

`amqDirectory=$(cd $BASEDIR/../rabbitProps/; pwd)`

Comment: I came across the command `dirname` so will try that and then if that fails then your method. By the way, would using cd in the following command change the directory?: `amqDirectory=$(cd $BASEDIR/../rabbitProps/; pwd)` E.g. if there was a command somewhere down the script that relied on the directory being on `${BASEDIR}`, would it still work assuming the directory is not in `/rabbitProps/`?

Comment: `realpath` is not a POSIX utility. Whether it exists or not is independent of the shell or its version. On Linux systems it is typically provided with the GNU Core utilities; on non-Linux systems, maybe try `abspath`.

Comment: Don't forget to quote the `BASEDIR` variable to prevent word splitting and globbing matches.

Comment: @bootlover123 directory is not changed to $BASEDIR/../rabbitProps/ after executing command as $(..) does the command substitution and it invokes sub-shell for executing commands